# Token and HTML site

Tags: php, html, telegram-bot

I figured out the file transfer, everything works as long as the token is registered in the code, without using a variable.

The first code is how the token was transferred to the site, judging by the echo line, everything is transferred from the file correctly.

```
<?php
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    ini_set('display_errors', 1);
    
    require 'vendor/autoload.php';
    
    use Dotenv\Dotenv;
    
    
    $dotenvPath = __DIR__;
    
    
    $dotenv = Dotenv::createImmutable(dirname(__DIR__));
    $dotenv->load();
    
    
    $TOKEN = $_ENV['TOKEN'];
    
    echo "TOKEN: $TOKEN";
          
           
    ?>
```

The second script is how the php script starts and so far a token of the form is specified here

6467892233:AAFSLMCUTXOMPSZD9ULXLOTEPARQ7S6VHI

everything is working well, the form is being sent.

The question is, how do I specify such not through a variable, which I get in the first code? Because when setting up

$TOKEN = "$_ENV['TOKEN']"; the script stops working

How do I specify the token correctly in my case?

```
<?php
// process_form.php


$TOKEN = "$_ENV['TOKEN']";
$TELEGRAM_CHAT_ID = "-1002017740885";


if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
   
    $product = $_POST['product'];
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $phone = $_POST['phone'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $attachments = $_FILES['attachments'];
    $invoice = $_FILES['invoice'];
/////
?>
```

Comment: If the JS is submitting the data directly to Telegram then yes you would need to have a token in the JS for it to use. And that means it's visible to anyone who uses the browser's Developer Tools to inspect what's going on. If you consider that to be a risk, then you'll need to make it so that your HTML form submits to a PHP script, and then your PHP script talks to Telegram - meaning that you can keep the token entirely on the server.

Comment: I don't even understand how this can be done...

Comment: What do you mean? You would simply have PHP make the HTTP request to Telegram, instead of Javacript doing it

Comment: Do I understand correctly that I need to rewrite a script written in js into php format?

Comment: Yes. It seems you've already tried to do that. So I suggest you rewrite your question completely now to be about how to upload files to telegram using php, and remove all the stuff about JS and tokens, because now it's a distraction from your current problem

Comment: @ADyson Can you tell me, please? Corrected the original question.

Comment: Thanks for the update. `stops working` how, exactly? Is there some error? In your second script, where is `$_ENV` being populated from? Did you load the `$dotenv` data again this time?

Comment: @ADyson I figured it out, I combined two codes into one and everything worked, thanks for suggesting that I don't need to declare a variable a second time. Thanks for the help.